# What does it mean that $\dim V=\dim F[x]/(p(x))=\deg p(x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, modules

$\dim V=\dim F[x]/I=\deg p(x)$ where $V$ is a $F[x]$-module and $I=(p(x))$

Here $p$ is irreducible.

$V$ is in fact a vector space over a field $F$, but by a linear operator $T\in End_F(V)$, made into a $F[x]$-module: $$f(T)\cdot v:=f(T(v))\in V$$
for all $v\in V,\,f\in F[x]$.

What I don't get is the meaning of $\dim F[x]/I$ and why the equalities hold.

Isn't the dimension of a ring, or, scalars is just 1?

**EDIT:** $(p(x))$ is maximal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that $F$ is a field.

Then the dimension is to be understood as dimension as vector space over $F$ and the equality is true because one can easily prove that if $\deg p(x)=d$ and $\bar x$ denotes the class of $x$ in the quotient then
$$
1,\bar x, \bar x^2,\ldots\bar x^{d-1}
$$
is a basis of $F[x]/(p(x))$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Could you tell me about the first equality?

Comment: @user642721: not sure what is "first equality" for you. I believe that $V=F[x]/(p(x))$ by definition (what else?).